# SQL with Date LOOP

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, recursive-query

I've been trying to write a query that returns the penultimate day of each month for 36 months, and this query should automatically return records for 36 months.

For example; such as 20201230 for December, 20210130 for January, 20210228 for February (excluding February). I will then update the dates specified in the column in my table this way.

It should be just like a loop or can I do it using cursor? By the way, the date should be parametric  Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 1):

The better way to do this is to use a tally function, dateadd, and eomonth.

Numbers function

```
create function [dbo].[fnNumbers](
  @zero_or_one   bit, 
  @n             bigint)
returns table with schemabinding as return
with n(n) as (select null from (values (1),(2),(3),(4)) n(n))
select 0 n where @zero_or_one = 0
union all
select top(@n) row_number() over(order by (select null)) n
from n na, n nb, n nc, n nd, n ne, n nf, n ng, n nh,
     n ni, n nj, n nk, n nl, n nm, n np, n nq, n nr;
```

Query

```
declare
  @start_dt         date='2020-12-25';

select dateadd(day, -1, eomonth(@start_dt, fn.n)) penult_dt
from dbo.fnNumbers(0, 35) fn;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you looking for ?

```
DECLARE @Start DATE='2020-12-25'

;WITH CTE
as
(
SELECT 1 Seq, DATEADD(DAY,-DAY(@Start),DATEADD(MONTH,1,@Start)) Dt
UNION ALL
SELECT Seq+1, DATEADD(DAY,-DAY(@Start),DATEADD(MONTH,Seq+1,@Start)) FROM CTE WHERE Seq+1 <37
)
SELECT FORMAT(Dt,'yyyyMMdd') Dates FROM CTE
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the penultimate day of the current month and of the following 36 months. Here is an option using a recursive query:

```
with cte as (
    select dateadd(month, 1, datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1)) as dt
    union all
    select dateadd(month, 1, dt) from cte where dt < dateadd(month, 36, getdate())
)
select dt, dateadd(day, -2, dt) as dt_penultimate 
from cte
```

The idea is to use the recursive query to generate a series of *starts* of month from the next month on. Then in the outer query we just offset each date by 2 days.

You can replace `getdate()` with a query parameter if you like.

If you must generate a span of more than 100 months, then you need to add `option(maxrecursion 0)` at the very end of the query.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=5212c060e9da85c5a3c67c6885c5acaa)**:

```
dt         | dt_penultimate
:--------- | :-------------
2021-01-01 | 2020-12-30    
2021-02-01 | 2021-01-30    
2021-03-01 | 2021-02-27    
2021-04-01 | 2021-03-30
...
```